# iPhoto not recognizing memory card, but mounts in Finder

Tags: photos.app, sd-card

I am running Lion with most recent version of iPhoto.

I can access the memory card in Finder without problem, but when I launch iPhoto the card does not show up to import photos it contains. I have tried rebuilding my entire iPhoto database and settings by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd> while the app is in the process of starting and selecting to rebuild.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the card is connected and what the card is?

Comment: Does the card contain a DCIM folder?

Comment: Using iMac and card is inside the SD slot on the side. Yes, it contains a DCIM folder. I should also mention the same card used to work in iPhoto on the same computer and I have imported before.

Answer (score 6):

Connect the memory card and launch the program **Image Capture** (found in the **Utilities** folder in both `/Applications/` or in Launchpad, if you're running Lion. In the lower left corner of the screen, there should be a menu that says *Connecting this camera opens...*; from the menu, select **iPhoto** from the list.

This *should* make iPhoto launch when you connect this memory card.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where my camera stopped appearing in iPhoto. It turned out that the problem was the camera contained too many photos (more than 1000) and I was just being impatient. When I waited for 4-5 minutes it finally appeared. Usually I don't have so many photos on the camera and I was used to it appeared in iphoto within a few seconds of being plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Open iPhoto, and then drag the SD card symbol that is on your desktop, into a folder in iPhoto (you can create a folder and name it whatever you want). Then iPhoto will import all the contents of that SD card!

Answer (score 0):

this answer is from 2017.  I only had videos on my SD card.  My Sd card would mount to the finder but not auto mount like usual in Photos.  My solution was to put the SD card in my camera, take one picture.  I inserted my SD card back in my iMac and Photos auto mounted the SD card like usual.  Hope this helps!